# Plato(n) and similar masculine names

Tags: etymology, greek

What is the etymology of dropped -n in ancient (Greek masculine) names ending with -on?
I mean Plato, Pluto, etc.

Curiously, the "n" is still preserved in derived words, like platonic or plutonic.

Another observation that may be related is that some non-Greek ancient names seemed to acquire -n in languages other than English, e.g., Cato becoming Caton.

Comment: Where is this coming from? how did  you get that peculiar idea?(out of my range)

Comment: I do not see anything peculiar about it, this was just an observation. English is not my first (or second) language, and the other languages I know do not miss the -n. Probably, they acquired Greek names directly, not via Latin as English did.

Comment: So you are a linguist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because Latin.

When the Ancient Greek names *Πλάτων, Πλούτων* and others were borrowed into Latin, they were changed into *Plato, Pluto*. I don't know if there's a single, well-known reason for this, but Latin had a lot of existing third-declension nouns ending in *-o, -onis*, and these Greek names were easiest to slot into this paradigm. These names then entered English by way of Latin, where they keep the peculiarity of losing the final *-n* except in derived forms.

Comment: It is possibly relevant that there are very few words in Latin ending in _-n_. (Almost all of those few are neuter nouns in _-men_).

Comment: I wonder if it means the derived forms entered English from some other languages that kept the -n. Or were they just formed by analogy with other derived words (such as "laconic").

Comment: Pluto was already Roman. The Greek underworld god is Hades.

Comment: @Oldcat, good point :). In my eagerness I forgot this.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests otherwise: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_%28mythology%29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_%28mythology%29): "Pluto (genitive Plutonis) is the Latinized form of the Greek Plouton".

Comment: @Oldcat Pluto is a latinization of the Greek _Πλούτων (pronounced Ploo-ton)_, which was a common epithet of Hades. In later years, _Plouton_ came to refer to the god exclusively, with _Hades_ referring to the Underworld instead.